# How to add XML data to HttpPut object?

Tags: android, http-put

I have a small problem. I am testing my Android REST class on http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER DEMO REST service.

Get method is OK, but I don't know how to use HttpPut or HttpPost.

```
HttpPut request = new HttpPut("http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/-2223");
```

But then I don't know how to add to this object XML data to put on server, for example:

```
<CUSTOMER xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<ID>2</ID>
<FIRSTNAME>Rick</FIRSTNAME>
<LASTNAME>Cortés Ribotta</LASTNAME>
<STREET>Calle Pública "B" 5240 Casa 121</STREET>
<CITY>Sydney100</CITY>
</CUSTOMER>
```

Thank you very much for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the XML content via `setEntity` where the `Entity` has to be a `StringEntity`.

```
mystr = ... // your XML
HttpPut request= new HttpPut(url);
request.setEntity(new StringEntity(mystr));
```